# Change Opacity of a Google Maps Tile Layer - API V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Does anyone have a good example or suggested strategy for dynamic opacity control of a custom tile layer in the google maps api V3?  If this helps to illustrate my goal or maybe inspire some solutions, here are some related example:

google maps, but with wrong api (v2)
http://crf.casa.ucl.ac.uk/screenRoute.aspx?s=386&d=105&w=False

an open layers equivalent
http://gemma.casa.ucl.ac.uk/apps/canvas/

Thanks

Comment: UPDATE: the strategy in the UCL campus map link above, although V2 API, still works in principle.  To describe the approach:
1. search each <IMG> div hosting a google map tile of a certain URL 2. change that div's alpha style declaration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've posted some code on github to do this:

https://github.com/gavinharriss/google-maps-v3-opacity-control/

Comment: Can you please let me know how we can change the Tile Layer opacity in Xamarin   , we have did following: var tileLayer = TileLayer.FromTileUri((x, y, zoom) =>

                new Uri($"URL")

            );

 

            GlasMap.TileLayers.Add(tileLayer); , Now I want to set the opacity of TileLayer for iOS in iOS Renderer